# Dropping duplicate items from Scrapy pipeline

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

My scrapy crawler collect data from ptt website, and input the crawling data into google spreadsheet by using gspread. my ptt spider parse latest 40 post on the ptt website everyday, and now i would like to drop duplicate data in this latest 40 post, for example, if the post_title or post_link is the same with yesterday, then don't need to parse this post into google spreadsheet.
i know i should use DropItem in scarpy, but literally i didn't know how to fix my code( i am a very new beginner in Python), and would like ask for help for this one, thanks.

> This is my ppt spider code

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    import scrapy
    # from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider
    from myFirstScrapyProject.items import MyfirstscrapyprojectItem
    
    class PttSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        count_page = 1
        name = 'ptt'
        allowed_domains = ['www.ptt.cc/']
        start_urls = ['https://www.ptt.cc/bbs/e-shopping/search?q=%E8%9D%A6%E7%9A%AE']+['https://www.ptt.cc/bbs/e-seller/search?q=%E8%9D%A6%E7%9A%AE']
        # start_urls = ['https://www.ptt.cc/bbs/e-shopping/index.html']
    
        def parse(self, response):
            items = MyfirstscrapyprojectItem()
            for q in response.css('div.r-ent'):
                items['push']=q.css('div.nrec > span.h1::text').extract_first()
                items['title']=q.css('div.title > a::text').extract_first()
                items['href']=q.css('div.title> a::attr(href)').extract_first()
                items['date']=q.css('div.meta > div.date ::text').extract_first()
                items['author']=q.css('div.meta > div.author ::text').extract_first()
                yield(items)
```

> and this is my pipeline

```
from myFirstScrapyProject.exporters import GoogleSheetItemExporter
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem

class MyfirstscrapyprojectPipeline(object):
    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self.exporter = GoogleSheetItemExporter()
        self.exporter.start_exporting()

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        self.exporter.finish_exporting()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.exporter.export_item(item)
        return item
```

> thanks to sharmiko, i rewrite it, but it seems doesn't work, what should i fix?

```
from myFirstScrapyProject.exporters import GoogleSheetItemExporter
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem

class MyfirstscrapyprojectPipeline(object):

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self.exporter = GoogleSheetItemExporter()
        self.exporter.start_exporting()

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        self.exporter.finish_exporting()

#    def process_item(self, item, spider):
#        self.exporter.export_item(item)
#        return item

#class DuplicatesTitlePipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.article = set()
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        href = item['href'] 
        if href in self.article:
            raise DropItem('duplicates href found %s', item)
        self.exporter.export_item(item)
        return(item)
```

> this is the code for export to google sheet

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from scrapy.exporters import BaseItemExporter

class GoogleSheetItemExporter(BaseItemExporter):
    def __init__(self):
        scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
        credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('pythonupload.json', scope)
        gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
        self.spreadsheet = gc.open('Community')
        self.worksheet = self.spreadsheet.get_worksheet(1)

    def export_item(self, item):
        self.worksheet.append_row([item['push'], item['title'], 
        item['href'],item['date'],item['author']])
```

Comment: did you comment `#class DuplicatesTitlePipeline(object):` this line on your code too? or just type on stackoverflow?

Comment: also don't forget to update `ITEM_PIPELINES` list in you `settings.py` every time you add new pipeline.

Comment: Sure, i added the `#class DuplicatesTitlePipeline(object):` to try to run, and also add this pipeline in the `settings.py`, but it seems doesn't work, so i just give it a # to ignore the code.

Comment: can you paste error traceback if it does not contain any sensitive information?

Comment: did you run the code and it added the duplicate elements? or this is the list which was previously collected.

Comment: @Sharmiko i mark the duplicated item with yellow mark, in case you can't understand chinese, you can see there's still lots of duplicated item everytime i run the code

Comment: my question is is this the new data or it was scraped earlier before you applied my solution?

Comment: this is the list i previous collect,  but i only want to collect the post which are not duplicate into google spreadsheet.

Comment: oh i applied your solution

Comment: can you delete whole spreadsheet and rerun the `spider` and we can see if it is adding duplicates or not?

Comment: ok. i'll try it now.

Comment: Now the spreadsheet don't have duplicated post, however,  because i have to run this code every morning, if i run this code tomorrow, the duplicated post will show (because i write this spider to parse the latest 40 post in this search result page: https://www.ptt.cc/bbs/e-shopping/search?q=%E8%9D%A6%E7%9A%AE)  and the post increase slowly, so if i run this code tmr to parse latest 40 post, it will conclude the post which i already parsed yesterday, i know i can use delete multiple in google spreadsheet, but i hope i could just write an code to avoid this situation

Comment: now i see. your duplicate check logic is incorrect

Comment: you need to open google spreadsheet load it into python code and check if there are duplicate elements there. I did not pay attention to that earlier.

Comment: Do you know which module i should use to load it into python code? or how should i rewrite the code? is it possible to do in scrapy ?

Comment: now you are just trying to check whether or not item is in set, this will only works on runtime and still your solution is incorrect, because you are not adding item to set.

Comment: yes, it is totally possible to do it in scrapy.

Comment: you already `gspread` library installed and you are using it.

Comment: Discussion we are having right now is not relevant to original question you posted, if you are stuck with google sheets, you have to do new research or ask new question on stackoverflow.

Comment: okok i see!! thank you for you help!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225087/discussion-between-claire-huang-and-sharmiko).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify your `process_item` function to check for duplicate elements and if it is found, you can just drop it.

```
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
...
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    if [ your duplicate check logic goes here]:
       raise DropItem('Duplicate element found')
    else:
       self.exporter.export_item(item)
       return item
```

Dropped items are no longer passed to other pipeline components. You can read more about pipelines [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html).

Comment: i also write a exporter.py to describe how to connect google sheet api, and input the data into google sheet. should i also fix the code in exporter.py? because i rewrite process_item function, but it seems doesn't work.

Comment: Could you share google sheet code and also paste full error message?

Comment: hi! i added the code in the post, please see the post~ thank you